# How to manipulate a line with the mouse?

Tags: c#, wpf, line, mouseevent

Is it possible to create a “resilient” line using C# in a wpf  which can be manipulated by the mouse while their starting and ending points remain stable? In particular I would like it to be resizable and its curve to change its direction following the move of the cursor which has previously captured the line? It is something you meet very often in graphical interfaces of desktop applications.

Is the manipulationDelta Class suitable for that? I want something like what is described in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee649090.aspx but with mouse manipulation, not touch.

Comment: Short answer yes, but maybe you should explain what you've tried or what problems you're running into?  Are you asking which WPF classes to use?

Comment: Ok, I am asking first if it is attainable to create a resilient line (on canvas) whose form can be changed by mouse move having initially grasped it with the mouse leftbutton. I am asking which classes or events I can use if there are any.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is very possible.

In a real application I would probably use some custom controls for the thumbs to handle the positioning & mouse capturing pieces so they're reusuable.

Here's a basic example of something like this.

Here's the XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <Canvas Name="myCanvas" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Line Name="myLine" X1="100" Y1="100" X2="200" Y2="200" Stroke="Black" />
    <Ellipse Name="thumb1" Fill="Blue" Width="10" Height="10" Canvas.Left="95" Canvas.Top="95" Cursor="Hand" MouseLeftButtonDown="OnPoint1Down" MouseLeftButtonUp="OnPoint1Up" MouseMove="OnPoint1Move" />
  </Canvas>
</Window>
```

And here's the code behind

```
  public partial class MainWindow : Window {
    public MainWindow() {
      InitializeComponent();
      }

    private void OnPoint1Down( object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e ) {
      Mouse.Capture( thumb1 );
      }

    private void OnPoint1Up( object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e ) {
      Mouse.Capture( null );
      }

    private void OnPoint1Move( object sender, MouseEventArgs e ) {

      if ( e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed ) {

        var point = e.GetPosition( myCanvas );

        myLine.X1 = point.X;
        myLine.Y1 = point.Y;

        Canvas.SetLeft( thumb1, point.X - thumb1.Width/2 );
        Canvas.SetTop( thumb1, point.Y - thumb1.Height/2 );
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: It is not exactly what I want. I don’ t want a straight line ,but a curve (or a line that can be curved) which the user could grasp with the mouse on a middle point and could bend, stretch and convulse it in any direction while its ending point remain stable.

Comment: @arjacsoh Just use a Path instead of a Line in WPF, but the idea is the same, make a some control to capture the mouse on mouse down and adjust the points of the Shape (whatever it is) on mouse move.